Accessing Java objects across container boundaries
Is it possible to invoke Java instance methods living in a host from a local Docker container through shared memory? If so, how?
Thus, from code running in a JVM J1, I’d like to run a Docker container locally (meaning on the same physical machine). In the client container, I’d run a JVM J2. I want now for Java instances living in J1 to be accessible from J2 (meaning, with i being an instance created by J1, invoking from J2 i.someMethod()). I’d like this to be as transparent as possible, thus, avoid writing serialization code for transferring the state of i from J1 to J2 and avoid writing code for sending and reading messages through sockets.
Here is a strategy that I thought about.

Creating the local Docker container from J1 seems easy enough using e.g. docker-java.
Sharing memory seems feasible thanks to Docker mechanisms.
Using FFM I could allocate a shared memory segment in J1 and access it from J2.
One thing that I ignore is whether J2 will indeed be able to access that memory segment as if J2 was not containerized, in other words, whether it is possible to let Docker share the memory in a way that will be transparent to the client code (meaning the processes running in the container), or whether it is necessary for the client code to use some special memory allocation mechanism (such as shmget?) to access the shared memory. In the latter case, can I somehow tell the JVM in J2 to use that special memory allocation mechanism to access the shared memory segment?

Note that (I think that) the above strategy turns the question into: is it possible to use FFM across container boundaries?
The reason I want to do this is to run untrusted code from the container, while allowing for J2 to invoke (selected) instance methods from J1.

I'm not really familiar with containers, but if it's possible to share memory with the container and access it from C code within the container, I don't see why you couldn't access the same memory through FFM. Note that you can not use that to share Java instances though, as the FFM API can't be used to write Java objects to off-heap memory (that would break the GC). So, you would have to serialize/deserialize them to/from the shared off-heap memory

@JornVernee “access it from C code within the container” ⇒ do you mean, transparently? I suspect that the C code would need to use something like mmap or shmget to access the host memory; using simple malloc would perhaps only reach container-private (not shared) memory; but I may have misunderstood something. “I don't see why you couldn't access the same memory through FFM” ⇒ I have some fear that FFM would not try to access the host memory, rather private memory, as it would not know to use mechanisms for reaching the shared memory rather than the container-private memory.

@JornVernee “you can not use that to share Java instances” ⇒ thanks, I have clarified what I meant with sharing which was indeed unclear.

"I suspect that the C code would need to use something like mmap or shmget to access the host memory" -> Yes, that is what I'd imagine too. Allocate memory in a process in the host, use some settings to make that memory visible in the container, then get a pointer to the memory in the container. At that point you can wrap it into a MemorySegment. But sill, you would need to invent some kind of protocol to communicate with the host, and you can't pass java objects through that protocol without some serialization.

@JornVernee Do you mean that I would have to write code in C that would allocate the required memory and pass messages back and forth? I was hoping that FFM would permit to invoke Java objects without me having to write code in C. I was contemplating just my Java code to start another Java process, not involving any C code of my own, and letting FFM (hopefully transparently) do the job.
Unrelatedly (I guess): I again edited to make it clearer that I do not want to pass Java objects, just references. (I suspect that I am missing your point though.)

You don't have to write C code. FFM let's you call C functions, so you can write the calls to the operating system APIs in Java. But again, you can not pass java objects/references through off-heap memory (which is what the shared memory you allocate would be). You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of the role and purpose of FFM though. It is not meant to connect JVMs together, it is meant to connect a JVM with a C library, or to let it interact with off-heap memory. Those are building blocks that could help, but they don't do what you want out of the box

@JornVernee “It is not meant to connect JVMs together” ⇒ I realize this but was hoping to use its memory sharing and its upcall features beyond their initial use case. Any idea which technology I could use to call an instance living in J1 from J2 across container boundaries, then, if it is possible at all? (More transparently than by messaging through sockets or writing serialization code, i.e. using something like FFM’s upcall feature.)

@JornVernee I believe that your comments provide an answer to my question, so if you want to turn them into an answer, I’ll accept that.
